# jquery-ui-multiselect-widget change selectedText on optgrouptoggle

Tags: jquery-ui, optgroup, multi-select

How i could change selectedText by optgrouptoggle?

https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
optgrouptoggle: function(event, ui){
   $("#select").multiselect('option', 'selectedText', ui.label);
}
```